# Unexpected behavior of Compile, Return and ;

Tags: compile

Could somebody explain why

```
test = Compile[{{x}},
      Return[x];
    ];
test[0.]
```

returns

```
Compile::cret: "The type of return values in Return[x]; are different. Evaluation will use the uncompiled function. "
```

while

```
test = Compile[{{x}},
      Return[x]
    ];
test[0.]
```

works as expected? Notice that the only difference is the semicolon at the end of `Return`.

Answer (score 8):

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8184548/do-return-behave-differently-in-compile-why) is closely related.  See [ruebenkoe's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8194565/695132) in particular.

I *think* you get this behaviour because:

1. Compiled code is typed, so `Compile` can only return one type of result (and the type needs to be a number, not a symbol)
2. When `Compile` analyses the code, it perceives it as something that returns `Null`.  `fun[x];` is equivalent to `fun[x]; Null`.  So even though you have a single `Return` which will *always* break out of the function (returning a number), `Compile` is not able to realize this.

   Further proof that this is the case is that the following compiles fine:

   ```
   test = Compile[{{x}}, Return[x]; 0.0]
   ```

Comment: Aha (I suspected as much), but then I would argue this is a bug in `Compile`. Since the return value is x and not 0.0. So it does not matter what comes after return.

Comment: Also this is strange as well `f = Function[x, Return[x];];
f[0.]`

Comment: `test = Compile[{{x}}, x];` on the other hand seems to work fine.

Comment: @image_doctor Yes, because in that case there return type can clearly only be one thing---a number.

Comment: @Ajasja In a slightly different situation such as `If[condition, Return[x]]; 0.0` it *does* matter what comes after return.  My suspicion is that it's not so easy for the compiler to tell these cases apart.  It's not smart enough to be able to analyse your example and conclude that everything after the `Return` can be ignored.  All it sees is that there are two potential exit points: one in `Return` and one after.  They have different return types, and in fact one of them has an illegal return type (a symbol).

Comment: @Ajasja Re your second comment: `Return` behaves differently in and outside `Compile` ... and I don't understand it entirely outside `Compile` ...

Comment: @Szabolcs This seems to behave as though there is an implicit return in compiled functions, so the use of `Return` is superfluous?

Comment: @image_doctor: "the use of `Return[]` is superfluous?" - not really, you might for instance want to break out of a loop within a compiled function with `Return[]`, for example.

Comment: @image_doctor Isn't there an implicit return in every function?  The last value in a `CompoundExpression` is returned.  Am I misunderstanding you?  Too see what a compiled function is made of precisely, use ``<<CompiledFunctionTools` `` then `CompilePrint`.  In the low level instruction meant for the MVM there is indeed an explicit `return`.

Comment: @J.M. ...`Loop`, functionally I do not understand ;)

Comment: @Szabolcs Yes, that was the point I was trying to form, I think.

Comment: @Szabolcs More explicitly,  there is an implicit `Return` at the end of the function ( in this case returning `Null` because of the `;`) and when you code a second `Return` which returns a number the two types do not match.

Comment: @image_doctor Yes, just like with any other Mathematica function, for example `f[] := (1;)` also returns `Null` (even if it's not printed)

Comment: @Szabolcs Is the implication that `Null` is not a number, so a compiled function can in fact return a type which is not a number ?

Comment: @Szabolcs "My suspicion is that it's not so easy for the compiler to tell these cases apart." I agree, it's not easy, but probably not impossible, this is why I would call this behaviour a bug. (But I'm very biased after one hour of wasted time wondering why my function does not compile :)

Comment: @Ajasja `f = Function[x, Return[x, CompoundExpression]]; f[0.]`. And there are no bugs in `Compile`, only undocumented features. ;)