# If doesn't compile if its output is the output of Compile?

Tags: compile

The smallest sample I can find to reproduce this problem is:

```
test = Compile[{}, If[True, 1]];
<< CompiledFunctionTools`
CompilePrint@test
```

> ```
> …………
>  1    R0 = MainEvaluate[ Function[{}, If[True, 1]][ ]]
>  2    Return
> ```

The problem disappears when the `If[]` is followed by a semicolon:

```
test = Compile[{}, If[True, 1];];
CompilePrint@test
```

> ```
> …………
> 1     if[ !B0] goto 3
> 2     goto 3
> 3     Return
> ```

or enclosed by a redundant `Do[]`:

```
test = Compile[{}, Do[If[True, 1], {1}]];
CompilePrint@test
```

> ```
> …………
> 1   I1 = I0
> 2   I3 = I2
> 3   goto 6
> 4   if[ !B0] goto 6
> 5   goto 6
> 6   if[ ++ I3 < I1] goto 4
> 7   Return
> ```

while a redundant `Table[]` won't help:

```
test = Compile[{}, Table[If[True, 1], {1}]];
CompilePrint@test
```

> ```
> …………
>
> 1   I1 = I0
> 2   I4 = I3
> 3   T(R1)0 = Table[ I1]
> 4   I2 = I3
> 5   goto 8
> 6   R1 = MainEvaluate[ Function[{}, If[True, 1]][ ]]
> 7   Element[ T(R1)0, I4] = R1
> 8   if[ ++ I2 < I1] goto 6
> 9   Return
> ```

This phenomenon may lead to a total failure of compilation when codes become more complicated:

```
ie = 200;
ez = ConstantArray[0., {ie + 1}];
hy = ConstantArray[0., {ie}];

f1 = Compile[{{steps}}, 
   Module[{ie = ie, ez = ez, hy = hy}, 
    Do[ez[[2 ;; ie]] = ez[[2 ;; ie]] + (hy[[2 ;; ie]] - hy[[1 ;; ie - 1]]);
     ez[[1]] = Sin[n/10];
     hy[[1 ;; ie]] = hy[[1 ;; ie]] + (ez[[2 ;; ie + 1]] - ez[[1 ;; ie]]), {n, steps}];
    ez]];

f2 = Compile[{{steps, _Integer}, {test, True | False}}, 
   Module[{ie = ie, ez = ez, hy = hy}, 
    Do[ez[[2 ;; ie]] = ez[[2 ;; ie]] + (hy[[2 ;; ie]] - hy[[1 ;; ie - 1]]);
     ez[[1]] = Sin[n/10];
     hy[[1 ;; ie]] = hy[[1 ;; ie]] + (ez[[2 ;; ie + 1]] - ez[[1 ;; ie]]), {n, steps}];
    If[test, ez]]];

f1[1500]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

> ```
> {0.0250000, Null}
> ```

```
f2[1500, True]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

> *Warnings……*
>
> ```
> {0.5730000, Null}
> ```

So, as the title said, `If` won't compile when its output is the output of `Compile`?

Of course it can be easily circumvented, but I wonder if there's a universal rule behind this, or it's just another unreasonable behavior of `Compile`?

Comment: Identical issue, and solution, to those discussed in [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/46315/bizarre-behavior-of-with-compile-and-break) question earlier today. In fact I'd be tempted to close this as a duplicate, except that I think it shows the issue a bit more clearly than the other question.

Comment: @OleksandrR. In fact it's that question that motivate me to ask this one (I've noticed this behavior for some time), I read it but still failed to notice it's an identical issue 囧.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a type incompatibility problem. The compiler must make an assignment to the output of `If` in order to return a value. `If[True, 1]` is equivalent to `If[True, 1, Null]`, and there is no type that can be assigned to both `1` and `Null`. You will get the same problem if you make an assignment to the `If` result when it isn't the final output of `Compile`:

```
CompilePrint @ Compile[{}, Block[{x}, x = If[True, 1]]; 2]
```

> ```
>       I0 = 1
>       I1 = 2
>       B0 = True
>       Result = I1
>
> 1 R0 = MainEvaluate[ Function[{}, If[True, 1]][ ]]
> 2 Return
> ```

I'm not sure why you don't get a message, in other cases you do:

```
CompilePrint @ Compile[{}, If[True, 1, {2, 3}]]
```

> Compile::cif: The types of the two results in If[True,1,{2,3}] are incompatible because their ranks are different. Evaluation will use the uncompiled function. >>
>
> ```
>       I0 = 1
>       T(I1)0 = {2, 3}
>       B0 = True
>       Result = R0
>
> 1 R0 = MainEvaluate[ Function[{}, If[True, 1, {2, 3}]][ ]]
> 2 Return
> ```

Note that if both returns from `If` are `Null` there is no problem:

```
CompilePrint @ Compile[{}, If[True, Null]]
```

> ```
>       B0 = True
>       Result = V17
>
> 1 if[ !B0] goto 3
> 2 goto 3
> 3 Return
> ```