# Stable fluids code for electromagnetic mixture application

Tags: differential-equations, performance-tuning, finite-difference-method, fluid-dynamics

This code has been translated from the original [Jos Stam code](https://www.dgp.toronto.edu/public_user/stam/reality/Research/pdf/ns.pdf) and improved with some Mathematica functions. It solves problem of viscous incompressible flow with electromagnetic force in a rectangle  with periodic boundary condition on one side and with Dirichlet condition on the other side. In the initial condition fluid velocity is zero, but density has unit step like distribution (for instance, liquids gold and silver). First we define initial data and boundary condition module:

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]

dif = 1/500; pec = 20; U0 = 0; V0 = 0; F0 = 3; dn0 = 1; kap = 5; n = \
31; n1 = n + 1; dt = 40./n^2; sm = 200; r = 20; a = dt dif n n; c = 
 ConstantArray[0, {n1, n1}]; d = ConstantArray[0, {n1, n1}]; den = 
 ConstantArray[0, {n1, n1}]; c0 = ConstantArray[0, {n1, n1}]; u0 = 
 ConstantArray[0., {n1, n1}]; v0 = ConstantArray[0., {n1, n1}]; u = 
 ConstantArray[0, {n1, n1}]; v = ConstantArray[0, {n1, n1}]; Do[
 den[[All, j]] = dn0 (1 + .3 Tanh[kap (n1/2 - j)]);, {j, n1}]; dnup = 
 den[[1, n1]]; dnd = den[[1, 1]];

periodic[n_, up_, ud_, ub_] := 
  Module[{bd = ub}, 
   Do[bd[[1, i]] = .5 (bd[[n, i]] + bd[[2, i]]); 
    bd[[n + 1, i]] = bd[[1, i]]; bd[[i, 1]] = ud; 
    bd[[i, n + 1]] = up;, {i, 2, n}]; 
   bd[[1, 1]] = .5 (bd[[2, 1]] + bd[[1, 2]]); 
   bd[[n + 1, n + 1]] = .5 (bd[[n, n + 1]] + bd[[n + 1, n]]); 
   bd[[n + 1, 1]] = .5 (bd[[n, 1]] + bd[[n + 1, 2]]); 
   bd[[1, n + 1]] = .5 (bd[[1, n]] + bd[[2, n + 1]]); bd];
```

Second, diffusion step module with Gauss-Seidel relaxation algorithm:

```
diffuse[n_, r_, a_, c_, c0_] := 
 Module[{c1 = c}, c1 = ConstantArray[0, {n + 1, n + 1}]; 
  Do[Do[Do[c1[[i, 
         j]] = (c0[[i, j]] + 
           a (c1[[i - 1, j]] + c1[[i + 1, j]] + c1[[i, j - 1]] + 
              c1[[i, j + 1]]))/(1 + 4 a);, {j, 2, n}];, {i, 2, n}]; 
   Do[c1[[1, i]] = c1[[n, i]]; c1[[n + 1, i]] = c1[[2, i]]; 
    c1[[i, 1]] = c0[[i, 1]]; 
    c1[[i, n + 1]] = c0[[i, n + 1]];, {i, 2, n}]; 
   c1[[1, 1]] = .5 (c1[[2, 1]] + c1[[1, 2]]); 
   c1[[n + 1, n + 1]] = .5 (c1[[n, n + 1]] + c1[[n + 1, n]]); 
   c1[[n + 1, 1]] = .5 (c1[[n, 1]] + c1[[n + 1, 2]]); 
   c1[[1, n + 1]] = .5 (c1[[1, n]] + c1[[2, n + 1]]);, {k, 0, r}]; 
  c1];
```

Advection step module:

```
advect[n_, d_, d0_, u_, v_, dt_] := 
 Module[{x, y, d1, dt0, i0, i1, j0, j1, s0, s1, t0, t1}, 
  d1 = ConstantArray[0, {n + 1, n + 1}]; dt0 = dt n; 
  Do[Do[x = i - dt0 u[[i, j]]; y = j - dt0 v[[i, j]]; 
     i0 = Which[x <= 1, 1, 1 < x < n, Floor[x], x >= n, n]; 
     i1 = i0 + 1; 
     j0 = Which[y <= 1, 1, 1 < y < n, Floor[y], y >= n, n];
     j1 = j0 + 1; s1 = x - i0; s0 = 1 - s1; t1 = y - j0; t0 = 1 - t1; 
     d1[[i, j]] = 
      s0 (t0 d0[[i0, j0]] + t1 d0[[i0, j1]]) + 
       s1 (t0 d0[[i1, j0]] + t1 d0[[i1, j1]]);, {j, 1, n + 1}];, {i, 
    1, n + 1}]; d1];
```

Projection step module:

```
project[n_, r_, u0_, v0_, u_, v_] := 
  Module[{ux = u, vy = v, div, p}, 
   p = ConstantArray[0, {n + 1, n + 1}]; 
   div = ConstantArray[0, {n + 1, n + 1}]; 
   ux = ConstantArray[0, {n + 1, n + 1}]; 
   vy = ConstantArray[0, {n + 1, n + 1}]; 
   Do[div[[i, 
       j]] = -.5 /
        n (u0[[i + 1, j]] - u0[[i - 1, j]] + v0[[i, 1 + j]] - 
         v0[[i, j - 1]]);, {i, 2, n}, {j, 2, n}]; 
   Do[Do[Do[
       p[[i, j]] = (div[[i, 
             j]] + (p[[i - 1, j]] + p[[i + 1, j]] + p[[i, j - 1]] + 
              p[[i, j + 1]]))/4;, {j, 2, n}], {i, 2, n}];, {k, 0, r}];
    Do[ux[[i, j]] = u0[[i, j]] - .5 n (p[[i + 1, j]] - p[[i - 1, j]]);
     vy[[i, j]] = 
     v0[[i, j]] - .5 n (p[[i, j + 1]] - p[[i, j - 1]]);, {i, 2, 
     n}, {j, 2, n}]; {ux, vy}];
```

Electromagnetic force:

```
Fx[t_, x_, y_] := 
 F0 ((y - .5) Sin[2 Pi t]^2 - (x - 0.5) Sin[2 Pi t] Cos[2 Pi t]); 
Fy[t_, x_, y_] := 
 F0 (-(x - .5) Cos[2 Pi t]^2 + (y - .5) Sin[2 Pi t] Cos[2 Pi t]);
```

One step module:

```
onestep[n_, step_, r_, a_, uin_, vin_, dt_] := 
 Module[{u1, v1, f1, f2, c, u, v, u0, v0}, 
  f1 = ConstantArray[0, {n + 1, n + 1}]; 
  f2 = ConstantArray[0., {n + 1, n + 1}]; 
  u0 = ConstantArray[0., {n + 1, n + 1}]; 
  v0 = ConstantArray[0., {n + 1, n + 1}]; 
  u = ConstantArray[0., {n + 1, n + 1}]; 
  v = ConstantArray[0., {n + 1, n + 1}]; 
  u1 = ConstantArray[0., {n + 1, n + 1}]; 
  v1 = ConstantArray[0., {n + 1, n + 1}]; u0 = uin; v0 = vin; 
  u0 = advect[n, c, u0, u0, v0, dt]; v0 = advect[n, c, v0, u0, v0, dt];
  u0 = periodic[n, 0, 0, u0]; v0 = periodic[n, 0, 0, v0];
  u0 = diffuse[n, r, a, c, u0]; v0 = diffuse[n, r, a, c, v0];
  u0 = periodic[n, 0, 0, u0]; v0 = periodic[n, 0, 0, v0];
  Do[f1[[i, j]] = 
    Fx[dt (step + .5), (i - 1)/n, (j - 1)/n]/den[[i, j]]; 
   f2[[i, j]] = 
    Fy[dt (step + .5), (i - 1)/n, (j - 1)/n]/den[[i, j]];, {i, 2, 
    n + 1}, {j, 2, n + 1}]; u0 += f1 dt; 
  v0 += f2 dt; {u1, v1} = project[n, r, u0, v0, u, v]; 
  u0 = periodic[n, 0, 0, u1]; v0 = periodic[n, 0, 0, v1]; {u0, v0}]
```

Numerical solution for the flow and density:

```
Do[{u0, v0} = onestep[n, step, r, a, u0, v0, dt]; uu[step] = u0; 
  vv[step] = v0; den = diffuse[n, r, a/pec, c, den]; 
  den = periodic[n, dnup, dnd, den]; 
  den = advect[n, c, den, u0, v0, dt]; 
  den = periodic[n, dnup, dnd, den]; 
  dd[step] = den;, {step, 0, sm}] // AbsoluteTiming
```

Visualization:

```
Do[lstu[k] = 
   Flatten[Table[{{(i - 1)/n, (j - 1)/n}, uu[k][[i, j]]}, {i, n1}, {j,
       n1}], 1]; 
  lstv[k] = 
   Flatten[Table[{{(i - 1)/n, (j - 1)/n}, vv[k][[i, j]]}, {i, n1}, {j,
       n1}], 1];, {k, 0, sm}];
Do[Uvel[i] = Interpolation[lstu[i], InterpolationOrder -> 3];, {i, 1, 
   sm}];
Do[Vvel[i] = Interpolation[lstv[i], InterpolationOrder -> 3];, {i, 1, 
  sm}]; Do[lst4[k] = 
   Flatten[Table[{{(i - 1)/n, (j - 1)/n}, dd[k][[i, j]]}, {i, n1}, {j,
       n1}], 1];, {k, 0, sm}];
Do[rh[k] = Interpolation[lst4[k], InterpolationOrder -> 3];, {k, 0, 
   sm}];

frames = Table[
   ContourPlot[rh[i][x, y], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, 
    ColorFunction -> "BlueGreenYellow", Frame -> False, 
    PlotRange -> All, ImageSize -> Small, MaxRecursion -> 2, 
    Contours -> 5, ContourStyle -> Yellow], {i, 0, sm}];

Export["D:\\Animation\\Periodic.gif", frames, 
 AnimationRepetitions -> Infinity]
```

[image: Figure 1]

The question is about code improvement. How we can reduce computation time?

Comment: You've localized `c` in definition of `onestep`, is it a typo? Also, you write `Module[{c1 = c}, c1 = ConstantArray[0, {n + 1, n + 1}]; ` in definition of `diffuse`, is it a quick repair?

Comment: @xzczd Thank you very much for your remarks. I don't remember my logic when I created this code. But code has been tested and it works not as a stable fluid only.  Also  improvements you made are very  nice.

Comment: I’m unfamiliar with this physics. Where does the force expression come from?

Comment: @Gilbert This force generated in the conducting fluid by the rotating magnetic field.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Let's `Compile`.

```
dif = 1/500; pec = 20; U0 = 0; V0 = 0; F0 = 3; dn0 = 1; kap = 5; n = 63(*31*); 
n1 = n + 1;(*dt=40./n^2;*)sm = 4 200; r = 20;(*a=dt dif n n;*)
(*c=ConstantArray[0.,{n1,n1}];*)
(*d=ConstantArray[0,{n1,n1}];*)
den = ConstantArray[dn0 (1 + .3 Tanh[-kap Range[-n1/2, n1/2]]), n1];
(*c0=ConstantArray[0,{n1,n1}];*)
u0 = ConstantArray[0., {n1, n1}]; 
v0 = ConstantArray[0., {n1, n1}];
(*u=ConstantArray[0,{n1,n1}];
  v=ConstantArray[0,{n1,n1}];*) 
(*Do[den[[All,j]]=dn0 (1+.3 Tanh[kap (n1/2-j)]);,{j,n1}];*)
(*dnup=den[[1,n1]];dnd=den[[1,1]];*)

periodic[n_, up_, ud_, ub_] := 
  Module[{bd = ub}, Do[bd[[1, i]] = .5 (bd[[n, i]] + bd[[2, i]]);
    bd[[n + 1, i]] = bd[[1, i]]; bd[[i, 1]] = ud;
    bd[[i, n + 1]] = up;, {i, 2, n}];
   bd[[1, 1]] = .5 (bd[[2, 1]] + bd[[1, 2]]);
   bd[[n + 1, n + 1]] = .5 (bd[[n, n + 1]] + bd[[n + 1, n]]);
   bd[[n + 1, 1]] = .5 (bd[[n, 1]] + bd[[n + 1, 2]]);
   bd[[1, n + 1]] = .5 (bd[[1, n]] + bd[[2, n + 1]]); bd];

diffuse[n_, r_, a_, c_, c0_] := 
  Module[{c1 = c},(*c1=ConstantArray[0,{n+1,n+1}];*)
   Do[Do[Do[
       c1[[i, j]] = (c0[[i, j]] + 
            a (c1[[i - 1, j]] + c1[[i + 1, j]] + c1[[i, j - 1]] + c1[[i, j + 1]]))/(1 + 
            4 a);, {j, 2, n}];, {i, 2, n}];
    Do[c1[[1, i]] = c1[[n, i]]; c1[[n + 1, i]] = c1[[2, i]];
     c1[[i, 1]] = c0[[i, 1]];
     c1[[i, n + 1]] = c0[[i, n + 1]];, {i, 2, n}];
    c1[[1, 1]] = .5 (c1[[2, 1]] + c1[[1, 2]]);
    c1[[n + 1, n + 1]] = .5 (c1[[n, n + 1]] + c1[[n + 1, n]]);
    c1[[n + 1, 1]] = .5 (c1[[n, 1]] + c1[[n + 1, 2]]);
    c1[[1, n + 1]] = .5 (c1[[1, n]] + c1[[2, n + 1]]);, {k, 0, r}];
   c1];

advect[n_, d0_, u_, v_, dt_] := 
  Module[{x, y, d1, dt0, i0, i1, j0, j1, s0, s1, t0, t1}, 
   d1 = ConstantArray[0, {n + 1, n + 1}]; dt0 = dt n;
   Do[Do[x = i - dt0 u[[i, j]]; y = j - dt0 v[[i, j]];
      i0 = Which[x <= 1, 1, 1 < x < n, Floor[x], True(*x≥n*), n];
      i1 = i0 + 1;
      j0 = Which[y <= 1, 1, 1 < y < n, Floor[y], True(*y≥n*), n];
      j1 = j0 + 1; s1 = x - i0; s0 = 1 - s1; t1 = y - j0; t0 = 1 - t1;
      d1[[i, j]] = 
       s0 (t0 d0[[i0, j0]] + t1 d0[[i0, j1]]) + 
        s1 (t0 d0[[i1, j0]] + t1 d0[[i1, j1]]);, {j, 1, n + 1}];, {i, 1, n + 1}]; d1];

project[n_, r_, u0_, v0_, u_, v_] := 
  Module[{ux = u, vy = v, div, p}, p = ConstantArray[0, {n + 1, n + 1}];
   div = ConstantArray[0, {n + 1, n + 1}];
   ux = ConstantArray[0, {n + 1, n + 1}];
   vy = ConstantArray[0, {n + 1, n + 1}];
   Do[div[[i, j]] = -.5/
        n (u0[[i + 1, j]] - u0[[i - 1, j]] + v0[[i, 1 + j]] - v0[[i, j - 1]]);, {i, 2, 
     n}, {j, 2, n}];
   Do[Do[Do[
       p[[i, j]] = (div[[i, j]] + (p[[i - 1, j]] + p[[i + 1, j]] + p[[i, j - 1]] + 
              p[[i, j + 1]]))/4;, {j, 2, n}], {i, 2, n}];, {k, 0, r}];
   Do[ux[[i, j]] = u0[[i, j]] - .5 n (p[[i + 1, j]] - p[[i - 1, j]]);
    vy[[i, j]] = v0[[i, j]] - .5 n (p[[i, j + 1]] - p[[i, j - 1]]);, {i, 2, n}, {j, 2, 
     n}]; {ux, vy}];

Fx[t_, x_, y_] := F0 ((y - .5) Sin[2 Pi t]^2 - (x - 0.5) Sin[2 Pi t] Cos[2 Pi t]);
Fy[t_, x_, y_] := F0 (-(x - .5) Cos[2 Pi t]^2 + (y - .5) Sin[2 Pi t] Cos[2 Pi t]);

onestep[n_, step_, r_, a_, uin_, vin_, dt_, c_] := 
 Module[{u1, v1, f1, f2(*,c*), u, v, u0, v0}, f1 = ConstantArray[0, {n + 1, n + 1}];
  f2 = ConstantArray[0., {n + 1, n + 1}];
  u0 = ConstantArray[0., {n + 1, n + 1}];
  v0 = ConstantArray[0., {n + 1, n + 1}];
  u = ConstantArray[0., {n + 1, n + 1}];
  v = ConstantArray[0., {n + 1, n + 1}];
  u1 = ConstantArray[0., {n + 1, n + 1}];
  v1 = ConstantArray[0., {n + 1, n + 1}]; u0 = uin; v0 = vin;
  u0 = advect[n, u0, u0, v0, dt]; v0 = advect[n, v0, u0, v0, dt];
  u0 = periodic[n, 0, 0, u0]; v0 = periodic[n, 0, 0, v0];
  u0 = diffuse[n, r, a, c, u0]; v0 = diffuse[n, r, a, c, v0];
  u0 = periodic[n, 0, 0, u0]; v0 = periodic[n, 0, 0, v0];
  Do[f1[[i, j]] = Fx[dt (step + .5), (i - 1)/n, (j - 1)/n]/den[[i, j]];
   f2[[i, j]] = Fy[dt (step + .5), (i - 1)/n, (j - 1)/n]/den[[i, j]];, 
   {i, 2, n + 1}, {j, 2, n + 1}]; u0 += f1 dt;
  v0 += f2 dt; {u1, v1} = project[n, r, u0, v0, u, v];
  u0 = periodic[n, 0, 0, u1]; v0 = periodic[n, 0, 0, v1]; {u0, v0}]

cf = With[{cg = Compile`GetElement, hp = HoldPattern, dv = DownValues}, 
    Hold@Compile[{{u0argu, _Real, 2}, {v0argu, _Real, 2}, {denargu, _Real, 
              2}, {sm, _Integer}, {n, _Integer}, {r, _Integer}, dif, pec, F0}, 
            Module[{u0 = u0argu, v0 = v0argu, uu, vv, dd, den = denargu, 
              c = Table[0., {n + 1}, {n + 1}], dt = 40./n^2, a, dnup = den[[1, n + 1]], 
              dnd = den[[1, 1]]}, a = dt dif n n; 
             uu = vv = dd = Table[0., {sm + 1}, {n + 1}, {n + 1}]; 
             Do[{u0, v0} = onestep[n, step, r, a, u0, v0, dt, c];
              uu[[step + 1]] = u0;
              vv[[step + 1]] = v0;
              den = diffuse[n, r, a/pec, c, den];
              den = periodic[n, dnup, dnd, den];
              den = advect[n, den, u0, v0, dt];
              den = periodic[n, dnup, dnd, den];
              dd[[step + 1]] = den;, {step, 0, sm}]; {uu, vv, dd}], 
            CompilationTarget -> C, RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"] /. dv@onestep /. 
         Flatten[dv /@ {Fx, Fy, advect, diffuse, periodic, project}] /. 
        hp@ConstantArray[c_, {i_, j_}] :> Table[0., {i}, {j}] /. 
       hp@Part[a__] :> cg[a] /. hp[cg[a__] = rhs_] :> (Part[a] = rhs) // 
     ReleaseHold // Last]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {1.375986, Null} *)

rst = cf[u0, v0, den, sm, n, r, dif, pec, F0]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {3.036883, Null} *)

(*
lst = 
   ListContourPlot[Transpose[#], ColorFunction -> "BlueGreenYellow", Contours -> 5, 
      PlotRange -> All, Frame -> False] & /@ 
    rst[[-1]]; // AbsoluteTiming
 *)
(* {28.801388, Null} *)

lst = 
   ArrayPlot[Transpose[#], ColorFunction -> "BlueGreenYellow", DataReversed -> True, 
      Frame -> None, PlotRangePadding -> None] & /@ rst[[-1]]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {6.044640, Null} *)

lst // ListAnimate
```

[image]

Notice I've increased `sm` and `n`. For `sm = 200; n = 31;` it only takes 0.2 second to calculate `rst` on my laptop, which is a 350x speed-up.

To understand why the code is modified in this manner, you may want to read

[How to make the code inside Compile conciser without hurting performance?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/47485/1871)

[How to define a function inside a Compile?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/145931/1871)

[Why is CompilationTarget -> C slower than directly writing with C?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/132130/1871)

[If doesn't compile if its output is the output of Compile?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/46345/1871)

[Memory usage of compiled function: C vs WVM](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/92178/1871)

Comment: Last step is very advanced  (+1).  Now with this improvement we can try to use this code with real time force like in  `CUDAFluidDynamics[]`.

Comment: @AlexTrounev I'm not sure what it is, but something seems to be wrong with the algorithm. Try `ArrayPlot[Transpose[Join @@ ConstantArray[# // Most, 2]], 
   ColorFunction -> "BlueGreenYellow", DataReversed -> True, Frame -> None, 
   PlotRangePadding -> None] &@rst[[-1, Floor[sm/2]]]`. (When time gets large e.g. `rst[[-1,-1]]`, the discontinuity becomes unobvious though. )

Comment: Do you mean in your code with `n = 63; sm=800` on the border? Even it is the stable fluid algorithm there are also instabilities happen due to higher Peclet number (in this case 20000). I will run several tests with this code to fix this problem.

Comment: @AlexTrounev Yeah, and for `rst[[-1, Floor[sm/3]]]` the roughness is obvious even with `n = 31; sm=200`.

Comment: Ah, I forgot that force has discontinuity on x for periodic solution. This discontinuity is not eliminated by viscosity on the first steps since we use explicit first order time integration step `u0 += f1 dt;  v0 += f2 dt`.  Therefore, if we need periodic solution without discontinuity, we should update force so that it has no discontinuity as well.

Comment: @alex Ah, that's true. Happy to know it's not the fault of the algorithm :) .

Comment: Jos Stam recommended to use `u0 += f1 dt;  v0 += f2 dt` as a first step, and then advection, diffusion, projection.  But this algorithm is less stable (not in this case).