# What's wrong with this FFT-based Von Kármán vortex street simulation?

Tags: differential-equations, fourier-analysis, algorithm, broken-code, fluid-dynamics

About 9 years ago, I came across [this interesting website](http://www.bugman123.com/FluidMotion/index.html), and found the following paragraph with a broken *Mathematica* code sample:

> [image]
>
> When fluid passes an object, it can leave a trail of vortices called a Von Kármán Vortex Street. This animation shows the vorticity where blue is clockwise and red is counter-clockwise. This simulation assumes unsteady, incompressible, viscid, laminar flow. For solenoidal flows, mass conservation can be achieved by taking the Fast Fourier Transform (FFT) of the velocity and then removing the radial component of the wave number vectors. The code was adapted from [Jos Stam’s C Source Code](https://web.archive.org/web/20030301070405/https://www.acm.org/jgt/papers/Stam01/solver.html) and [paper](https://www.dgp.toronto.edu/public_user/stam/reality/Research/pdf/jgt01.pdf) which is patented by Alias.
>
> ```
> (* Note: Something is wrong with this Mathematica code. 
>    Please tell me if you find out what it is. runtime: 14 seconds *)
>
> n = 64; dt = 0.3; mu = 0.001; v = Table[{0, 0}, {n}, {n}];
>
> Do[
>    Do[If[i < 5, v[[i, j]] = {0.1, 0}]; 
>       If[(i - n/4)^2 + (j -n/2)^2 < 4^2, v[[i, j]] = {0, 0}], 
>       {i, 1, n}, {j, 1, n}]; 
>
>    ui = ListInterpolation[v[[All, All, 1]]]; 
>    vi = ListInterpolation[v[[All, All, 2]]]; 
>    v = Table[{i2, j2} = {i, j} - n dt v[[i, j]]; 
>              {ui[i2, j2], vi[i2, j2]}, {i, 1, n}, {j, 1, n}]; 
>
>    v = Transpose[Map[Fourier[v[[All, All, #]]] &, {1, 2}], {3, 1, 2}]; 
>    v = Table[x = Mod[i + n/2, n] - n/2; 
>              y = Mod[j + n/2, n] - n/2; 
>              k = x^2 + y^2; 
>              Exp[-k dt mu] If[k > 0, (v[[i, j]].{-y, x}/k){-y, x}, v[[i, j]]], 
>              {i, 1, n}, {j, 1, n}]; 
>    v = Transpose[Map[Re[InverseFourier[v[[All, All, #]]]] &,{1,2}], {3, 1, 2}]; 
>
>    ListDensityPlot[Table[((v[[i + 1, j, 2]] - v[[i - 1, j, 2]]) - 
>                           (v[[i, j + 1, 1]] - v[[i, j - 1, 1]]))/2, 
>                          {j, 2, n - 1}, {i, 2, n - 1}], 
>                    Mesh -> False,Frame->False,ColorFunction -> (Hue[2#/3] &)], 
>   {t, 1, 25}];
> ```

Since then, every a year or two, I would be seized by a whim and try to fix the broken code, and fail then. And yes, I just failed one more time :D . So I think it may be the time to cry out loud: Why doesn't this sample work? How can it be fixed? By "doesn't work", I mean the obtained simulation result isn't even close to the GIF shown above. As an example, the following is the `ListDensityPlot` for `t == 25`:

[image]

I know there exist multiple ways to simulate vortex street, but in this question I'm particularly interested in fixing this code sample.

Several possible issues I can spot:

1. The `ListDensityPlot` is inside a `Do` loop, this is probably because the code is written in a early version of *Mathematica*, and `*Plot` is automatically `Print`ed at that time, as discussed in [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/47123/1871). This isn't a big problem, we just need to e.g. use `Table` instead of the outermost `Do`.
2. `ui` and `vi` should be periodic, this can be easily fixed with e.g.

   ```
   {ui, vi} = Module[{ui = #}, ui[[-1]] = ui[[1]]; ui[[All, -1]] = ui[[All, 1]]; 
       ListInterpolation[ui, InterpolationOrder -> 1, 
        PeriodicInterpolation -> True]] & /@ Transpose[v, {2, 3, 1}]
   ```

   but fixing this won't fix the simulation.
3. The original C code normalizes the velocity by dividing it by `n^2` as the last step, <strike>but adding this step to  *Mathematica* code doesn't fix the code.</strike> this is not needed for *Mathematica* code, because according to the [document of fftw](https://www.fftw.org/fftw2_doc/fftw_3.html), the convention of fftw is amount to `FourierParameters -> {-1, 1}`. The default setting of `Fourier` is `FourierParameters -> {0, 1}` i.e. the normalization is already done.
4. The grid used for simulation seems to be too coarse, but adjusting various parameters in the code doesn't seem to help. (I admit my adjustion is somewhat blind, though. )

For your convenience, the following is the code sample aiming at fixing the mentioned issues above. Of course, it still *doesn't work*:

```
n = 128; dt = 0.3; mu = 0.001; nt = 50;
v = Table[{0., 0.}, {n}, {n}];
separate = Transpose[#, {2, 3, 1}] &;
combine = Transpose[#, {3, 1, 2}] &;

vlst = Table[Do[If[i < 1 + n/16, v[[i, j]] = {0.1, 0.}];
                If[(i - n/4)^2 + (j - n/2)^2 < (n/16)^2, 
                   v[[i, j]] = {0., 0.}], {i, n}, {j, n}];
    {ui, vi} = 
     Module[{umat = #}, umat[[-1]] = umat[[1]]; 
                        umat[[All, -1]] = umat[[All, 1]];
                        ListInterpolation[umat, InterpolationOrder -> 1, 
                        PeriodicInterpolation -> True]] & /@ separate@v;  
    v = Table[{i2, j2} = {i, j} - n dt v[[i, j]];
              {ui[i2, j2], vi[i2, j2]}, {i, n}, {j, n}];
    v = Fourier /@ separate@v // combine;
    v = Table[x = Mod[i + n/2, n] - n/2;
              y = Mod[j + n/2, n] - n/2;
              k = x^2 + y^2;
              Exp[-k dt mu] If[k > 0, (v[[i, j]] . {-y, x}/k) {-y, x}, 
                                      v[[i, j]]], 
              {i, n}, {j, n}];
    v = InverseFourier /@ separate@v // combine // Re, 
    {t, nt}]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {24.4562, Null} *)
vortex = Compile[{{v, _Real, 3}}, 
                 With[{n = Length@v}, 
                      Table[((v[[i + 1, j, 2]] - v[[i - 1, j, 2]]) - 
                             (v[[i, j + 1, 1]] - v[[i, j - 1, 1]]))/2, 
                            {j, 2, n - 1}, {i, 2, n - 1}]]];
arrayplot = 
  ArrayPlot[#, DataReversed -> True, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"] &;
vortex@vlst[[-1]] // arrayplot
```

[image]

---

### Update

This is a bit embrassing: there exists another simple mistake in the implementation, if it's fixed, the vortex street will be obtained with minimal parameter adjustion. In order not to waste the bounty, I'd like not to make the answer public for the moment. The bounty will be awarded to the first answerer figuring out the mistake and obtaining the vortex street (not necessarily exactly the same as the GIF above).

---

### Update 2: Hint

Since the bounty will be expired in 23 hours but nobody has figured out the answer so far, let me give a hint: moving the cursor with mouse, the code can be fixed within 5 keystrokes.

Comment: Maybe it would help if you make your post self-contained. For instance, what equations you are trying to implement?  What exactly is the problem (apart from it wouldn't work)? Notice that attached paper is not very informative, not even a single equation there. It is hard to fix something that is not even written out.

Comment: How you tried to run the c++ code to see if it is producing the right picture?

Comment: @yarchik According to my understanding, this algorithm is related to NS equation for incompressible flow (together with the mass continuity equation), but it doesn't solve the PDE in a rigorous manner, for example, it simulates the viscosity of flow by multiplying a `Exp[-k dt mu]` term to the velocity in frequency domain. The problem is, in principle we should get a simulation result similar to the GIF in the question, but currently the density plot of the calculated vorticity is vastly different from it.

Comment: @yarchik "Notice that attached paper is not very informative, not even a single equation there." Yeah, this is annoying, but it shows a full C code sample, and the _Mathematica_ code sample **seems** to be a proper translation for the given algorithm (Except for those mentioned in possible issues above. Given that the sample doesn't work for the moment, I've probably missed something). I did attempt to test the original C code sample, but sadly it calls a library only available in Linux, I don't even know how to setup it in Windows. (I know little about C and Linux. )

Comment: I doubt that the code matches the visualization. The paper can handle only periodic BCs. Are you familiar with Fourier Pseudospectral methods?

Comment: @yarchik As to NS equation, one possible reference is the document :) (You can e.g. search "navier" in the page https://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/tutorial/SolvingPDEwithFEM.html ) As to the b.c., the periodic b.c. is imposed by the fast Fourier transform. (FFT will enforce the data to be periodic. ) The wall condition at the cylinder is imposed by the line `If[(i - n/4)^2 + (j -n/2)^2 < 4^2, v[[i, j]] = {0, 0}]`, which looks reasonable (at least to me). The line `If[i < 5, v[[i, j]] = {0.1, 0}]` plays the role of driven force BTW.

Comment: @ConvexHull According to my understanding, the periodic b.c. won't be a problem here, because the code simulates viscous flow. For a large enough domain, the velocity near the boundary should be close to 0, so periodic b.c. should be a good enough approximation for an infinitely large domain. As to Fourier pseudospectral method, I think I understand the principle, but who knows…

Comment: @yarchik I'd argue the information is enough. The algorithm is published and in public. The question is why the implementation doesn't give a reasonable result? I admit the question is far beyond ideal. (That's why I didn't post it in past 9 years! ) But it's already an answerable question, it's just hard.

Comment: @xzczd Concerning your Update, do you mean your implementation or code from website?

Comment: @Alex I mean mine i.e. we only need to correct one more simple mistake (well, perhaps I should not call it "simple" given that nobody notices it so far?) on my corrected code, and adjust the parameters a bit.

Comment: @Alex If you're asking if the mistake is made by me: No, it's inherited from the original _Mathematica_ code.

Comment: @xzczd How does the original code handle the division by zero for $k=0$? I am no Mathematica user and I can only see a if condition for $k>0$. Generally the integral mean is explicitly chosen to be an arbitrary constant, different to Alex example.

Comment: @ConvexHull For `If[cond, a, b]`, if `cond` evaluates to `True`, `a` is evaluated, if `cond` evaluates to `False`, `b` is evaluated. (The online document is [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/If.html) BTW. ) So, for $k=0$, `v[[i,j]]` is returned. This is also the strategy taken by the original C code.

Comment: To the downvoter, I am interested in what's wrong with my question, would you please elaborate. I'm not trying to complain here, I just want improve my question if possible.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Finally, rnotlnglgq finds [the correct answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/275111/1871) in time, so let me share my answer, too :) .

First I'd like to explain a bit more about the theoretical basis of the mass conservation correction in the algorithm, given the original paper is a bit brief. In 2D Cartesian coordinates, the continuity equation of incompressible flow is
$\newcommand{\f}{\frac}$
$\newcommand{\p}{\partial}$
$$\f{\p u(x,y)}{\p x}+\f{\p v(x,y)}{\p y}=0$$

Now, if the $(u(x,y),v(x,y))$ field is *well-behaved*, and is periodic or defined on an infinite domain, then we can apply Fourier transform or [finite Fourier transform](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/155818/1871) to the equation and obtain

$$\omega _x \mathcal{F}_{x,y}[u(x,y)]\left(\omega _x,\omega _y\right)
+\omega _y \mathcal{F}_{x,y}[v(x,y)]\left(\omega _x,\omega _y\right)=0$$

where $\mathcal{F}_{x,y}[u(x,y)]\left(\omega _x,\omega _y\right)$ stands for 2D Fourier transform/finite Fourier transform of $u(x,y)$. Clearly it's equivalent to

$$(\omega _x,\omega _y)\cdot (\mathcal{F}_{x,y}[u(x,y)]\left(\omega _x,\omega _y\right),\mathcal{F}_{x,y}[v(x,y)]\left(\omega _x,\omega _y\right))=0$$

i.e. the projection of 2D Fourier transform/finite Fourier transform of $(u,v)$ in $(\omega _x,\omega _y)$ direction should be zero, otherwise the continuity equation won't hold.

In the algorithm `Fourier` has been used for numerically calculate Fourier transform/finite Fourier transform, but the output of `Fourier` is arranged in a somewhat special way which is discussed in detail in e.g. [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/33625/1871), so we need to shift the frequency. This is **incorrectly** done in original code as

```
…
x = Mod[i + n/2, n] - n/2;
y = Mod[j + n/2, n] - n/2;
…
```

The correct one, as shown by rnotlnglgq, should be

```
…
x = Mod[i + n/2-1, n] - n/2;
y = Mod[j + n/2-1, n] - n/2;
…
```

or equivalently:

```
…
x = Mod[i - 1, nx, -nx/2];
y = Mod[j - 1, ny, -ny/2];
…
```

One may find this suspicious at first glance. "Yeah, the original code is incorrect, but is it that bad? It's almost correct, and I'd expect it producing an almost correct result." This is the surprising part, the algorithm is very sensitive to the correctness of frequency shift. Such a small mistake ruins everything. (BTW, avoiding the singularity at `k == 0` with e.g. `k = x^2 + y^2 + 10^-16.` ruins the algorithm, too. )

Now that the algorithm is fixed, let me show an optimized implementation:

```
SetAttributes[compile, HoldAll];
compile[argu__] := 
 With[{cg = Compile`GetElement}, 
    Hold@Compile[argu, RuntimeOptions -> "Speed", CompilationTarget -> "C"] /. 
      Part -> cg /. HoldPattern[cg[a__] = rhs_] :> (Part[a] = rhs)] // ReleaseHold //
   Last

vortex = compile[{{v, _Real, 3}}, Module[{nx, ny}, {nx, ny} = Dimensions@v[[1]];
    Table[((v[[2, i + 1, j]] - v[[2, i - 1, j]]) - (v[[1, i, j + 1]] - 
          v[[1, i, j - 1]]))/2, {j, 2, ny - 1}, {i, 2, nx - 1}]]];

interrule = inter[valueL_, valueR_, scale_] :> (1 - scale) valueL + scale valueR;

force…and…advection = 
  Hold@compile[{{arg, _Real, 3}, {dt, _Real}}, 
       Module[{u, v, unew, vnew, nx, ny, inew, jnew, iL, jL, iR, jR},
        {u, v} = arg;
        {nx, ny} = Dimensions@v;
        unew = vnew = Table[0., {nx}, {ny}];
        (*Alternative force:*)
        (*Do[v[[1,j]]={.1,0.},{j,ny}];*)
        Do[If[i < 1 + nx/16, u[[i, j]] = 0.1; v[[i, j]] = 0.];
         If[(i - nx/4)^2 + (j - ny/2)^2 < (nx/16)^2, u[[i, j]] = 0.; 
          v[[i, j]] = 0.], {i, nx}, {j, ny}];
        Do[
         inew = Mod[i - nx dt u[[i, j]], nx - 1, 1];
         jnew = Mod[j - nx dt v[[i, j]], ny - 1, 1];
         iL = Floor@inew; jL = Floor@jnew;
         iR = iL + 1; jR = jL + 1;
         unew[[i, j]] = interfunc[u];
         vnew[[i, j]] = interfunc[v];
         , {i, nx}, {j, ny}]; {unew, vnew}]] /. 
     interfunc[v_] :> 
      inter[inter[v[[iL, jL]], v[[iL, jR]], jnew - jL], 
       inter[v[[iR, jL]], v[[iR, jR]], jnew - jL], inew - iL] //. interrule // 
   ReleaseHold;
viscosity…and…conservation = 
  compile[{{arg, _Complex, 3}, dt, mu}, Module[{x, y, nx, ny, k, u, v},
    {u, v} = arg; {nx, ny} = Dimensions@v;
    Do[x = Mod[i - 1, nx, -nx/2];
     y = Mod[j - 1, ny, -ny/2];
     k = x^2 + y^2;
     With[{coef = Exp[-k dt mu], mid = -y u[[i, j]] + x v[[i, j]]},
      If[k > 0,
       u[[i, j]] = -y mid/k coef; v[[i, j]] = x mid/k coef, 0.]], {i, nx}, {j, ny}];
    {u, v}]];

nx = 128; ny = nx; dt = 0.3; mu = 0.001; nt = 800;
v = Table[0., {2}, {nx}, {ny}];
separate = Transpose[#, {2, 3, 1}] &;
combine = Transpose[#, {3, 1, 2}] &;
vlst = Table[v = force…and…advection[v, dt];
    v = Fourier /@ v;
    v = viscosity…and…conservation[v, dt, mu];
    v = InverseFourier /@ v // Re, {t, nt}]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {3.28788, Null} *)

cut = nx/16;
disk = Graphics[{Opacity[1/2], Disk[{nx/4 - cut, ny/2}, nx/16]}];
arrayplot = 
  Show[ArrayPlot[#, DataReversed -> True, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
     ImageSize -> nx, PlotRange -> {0, 1}], disk] &;

piclst = arrayplot /@ 
    Rescale[vortex@separate@combine[#][[Round@cut ;;]] & /@ 
      vlst[[;; ;; 10]]]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {2.35815, Null} *)

piclst // ListAnimate
```

[image]

### Remark

1. If you don't have a C compiler installed, please take away the `CompilationTarget -> "C"` option and the `// Last` in definition of `compile`. I do recommend you to install one, though.
2. The color of `argu` in definition of `compile` is red, but don't worry.
3. You may have noticed the obtained flow is different from those obtained with the fixed original code. This isn't surprising because the implementations for periodic linear interpolation aren't exactly the same. Since the algorithm isn't a rigorous PDE solver, but more of a creator for something looks like flow, I'd like to leave the discrepency alone.
4. If `nx` is small, `ListDensityPlot` isn't a bad choice for visualization. The following is another possible definition of `arrayplot` using `ListDensityPlot`:

   ```
   arrayplot =
       ListDensityPlot[#, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", ImageSize -> 4 nx,
             PlotRange -> {0, 1}, AspectRatio -> Automatic, Epilog -> disk[[1]],
           Mesh -> False, Frame -> False] &;
   ```
5. You may have noticed I've avoided arithmetic operation on lists in the code. For example,  `x = Mod[i - 1, nx, -nx/2]; y = Mod[j - 1, ny, -ny/2]` can be shortened to `{x, y} = Mod[{i, j} - 1, {nx, ny}, -{nx, ny}/2]`. I don't do this because it significantly slows down the code when compiling to C.
6. I've used `nx = 128`, but even `nx = 32` is enough to generate observable vortex street.
7. Viscosity turns out to be unnecessary to produce vortex street i.e. the `Exp[-k dt mu]` in code can actually be taken away. The resulting pattern looks more beautiful (at least in my view):

   [image]
8. A large enough `ny` is necessary, if we cut `ny` to `ny = nx/2`:

   [image]

   As we can see, the obtained pattern isn't that great.

---

### A Version 3 Compatible Implementation

Just for fun, I further modified the code so it works from *v3.0* to *v13.1*:

```
Off[General::spell]
Off[General::spell1]

SetAttributes[compile, HoldAll];

If[$VersionNumber < 8, compile[argu__] := Compile[argu], 
  compile[argu__] := 
   With[{cg = Compile`GetElement}, 
     Hold@Compile[argu, RuntimeOptions -> "Speed", CompilationTarget -> "C"] /. 
       Part -> cg /. HoldPattern[cg[a__] = rhs_] :> (Part[a] = rhs)] // ReleaseHold(*//
  Last*)];

vortex = compile[{{v, _Real, 3}}, Module[{nx, ny}, {nx, ny} = Dimensions@v[[1]];
    Table[((v[[2, i + 1, j]] - v[[2, i - 1, j]]) - (v[[1, i, j + 1]] - 
          v[[1, i, j - 1]]))/2, {j, 2, ny - 1}, {i, 2, nx - 1}]]];

interrule = inter[valueL_, valueR_, scale_] :> (1 - scale) valueL + scale valueR;

force…and…advection = 
  Hold@compile[{{arg, _Real, 3}, {dt, _Real}}, 
       Module[{u, v, unew, vnew, nx, ny, inew, jnew, iL, jL, iR, jR}, {u, v} = arg;
        {nx, ny} = Dimensions@v;
        unew = vnew = Table[0., {nx}, {ny}];
        (*Alternative force:*)(*Do[v[[1,j]]={.1,0.},{j,ny}];*)
        Do[If[i < 1 + nx/16, 
              u[[i, j]] = 0.1; v[[i, j]] = 0., 
              0.];
         If[(i - nx/4)^2 + (j - ny/2)^2 < (nx/16)^2, 
            u[[i, j]] = 0.;v[[i, j]] = 0., 
            0.], {i, nx}, {j, ny}];
        Do[inew = Mod[i - nx dt u[[i, j]] - 1, nx - 1] + 1;
         jnew = Mod[j - nx dt v[[i, j]] - 1, ny - 1] + 1;
         iL = Floor@inew; jL = Floor@jnew;
         iR = iL + 1; jR = jL + 1;
         unew[[i, j]] = interfunc[u];
         vnew[[i, j]] = interfunc[v];, {i, nx}, {j, ny}]; {unew, vnew}]] /. 
     interfunc[v_] :> 
      inter[inter[v[[iL, jL]], v[[iL, jR]], jnew - jL], 
       inter[v[[iR, jL]], v[[iR, jR]], jnew - jL], inew - iL] //. interrule // 
   ReleaseHold;

viscosity…and…conservation = 
  compile[{{arg, _Complex, 3}, dt, mu}, 
   Module[{x, y, nx, ny, k, u, v}, {u, v} = arg; {nx, ny} = Dimensions@v;
    Do[
     x = Mod[i - 1 + nx/2, nx] - nx/2;
     y = Mod[j - 1 + ny/2, ny] - ny/2;
     k = x^2 + y^2;
     With[{coef = Exp[-k dt mu], mid = -y u[[i, j]] + x v[[i, j]]}, If[k > 0,
       u[[i, j]] = -y mid/k coef; v[[i, j]] = x mid/k coef, 0.]], {i, nx}, {j, ny}];
    {u, v}]];
(*Obtained with FindFormula:*)
rainbowcore = 
  compile[s, {0.4812174314044116` - 3.7442543302272293` s + 
     21.92055029805457` s^2.` - 63.09750453225312` s^3.` + 
     108.54708507988678` s^4.002496025211754` - 94.17958853869598` s^5.` + 
     30.931639079029107` s^6.`, 0.12036767137989492`
     - 1.2465284793071336` s + 26.535159362530283` s^2 - 94.55369722465234` s^3 + 
     155.26914677786502` s^4 - 124.36433714169121` s^5 + 38.37235660032842` s^6, 
    0.5273478922125036`
     + 2.1548191214387797` s + 2.632115374325022` s^2 - 50.21875613715874` s^3 + 
     112.94351047860702` s^4 - 98.6320053106276` s^5 + 30.726738288661593` s^6}];
rainbowfunc = RGBColor @@ rainbowcore@# &;

If[$VersionNumber < 5.1, Rescale = (# - Min[#])/(Max[#] - Min[#]) &];
nx = 64; ny = nx; dt = 0.3; mu = 0.001; nt = 800;
v = Table[0., {2}, {nx}, {ny}];
separate = Transpose[#, {2, 3, 1}] &;
combine = Transpose[#, {3, 1, 2}] &;
vlst = Table[v = force…and…advection[v, dt];
    v = Fourier /@ v;
    v = viscosity…and…conservation[v, dt, mu];
    v = InverseFourier /@ v // Re, {t, nt}]; // Timing

cut = nx/16;
If[$VersionNumber < 6, disk = Disk[{nx/4 - cut, ny/2}, nx/16];
  arrayplot = 
   ListDensityPlot[#, ColorFunction -> rainbowfunc, ImageSize -> 4 nx, 
     PlotRange -> {0, 1}, AspectRatio -> Automatic, Epilog -> disk, Mesh -> False] &,
   disk = {Opacity[1/2], Disk[{nx/4 - cut, ny/2}, nx/16]};
  arrayplot = 
   ArrayPlot[#, DataReversed -> True, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", Epilog -> disk, 
     ImageSize -> 4 nx, PlotRange -> {0, 1}] &;];
piclst = arrayplot /@ 
    Rescale[vortex@
        separate@Drop[combine[#1], Round[cut]] & /@ (Transpose[
         Partition[vlst, 10]][[1]])]; // Timing


If[$VersionNumber < 6, "You can use Ctrl+Y to create animation. ", 
 piclst // ListAnimate]
```

Warning: since packed array isn't yet introduced in *v3.0*, the code is rather slow therein. For `nx = 64; ny = nx/2`, the timing is about 461 seconds on 2GHz machine.

The timing will reduce to about 17 seconds in *v4*, and about 15 seconds in *v5*.

Comment: It is very good solution (+1).

Comment: The name for module `viscosity\[Ellipsis]and\[Ellipsis]conservation` is not right. We don't use conservation, not solve equation $\nabla.\vec{v}$ in this algorithm. The last step of predictor-corrector algorithm is projection. For this step we can use FFT. Jos Stam combined diffusion step and projection step in one step. So, the right name could be  `viscosity\[Ellipsis]and\[Ellipsis]projection`.

Comment: @Alex Jam Stam uses the term "Conservation of Mass" in his paper…: https://i.stack.imgur.com/idgyj.png

Comment: Yes, but he used name   `Project` for projection module in the paper https://www.dgp.toronto.edu/public_user/stam/reality/Research/pdf/ns.pdf . The advance of the projection step is that we compute pressure gradient and divergent free velocity field in one step. See my answer on https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/261185/3d-stable-fluids-algorithm-to-simulate-transition-from-laminar-to-turbulent-flow

Comment: @AlexTrounev I think it's not surprising. The paper you linked is a rigorous PDE solver, and the projection is imposed on the whole RHS $-(\mathbf{u}\cdot\nabla)\mathbf{u}+\nu \nabla^2 \mathbf{u}+\mathbf{f}$, but the algorithm discussed in this question is, as mentioned above, more of a creator of something looks like a flow, and only the speed field is considered, so it's OK to call/explain this step as "force our field to be mass conserving".

Comment: Finally, I found out how $k_x, k_y$ can be extracted from FFT matrix. Also, the diffusion step could be improved with using predictor-corrector algorithm. See my final answer and code.  :)

Answer (score 10):

I found the index should start from `0` instead of `1`. This affects the (squared) wave number `k`.

```
x = Mod[i + n/2, n] - n/2;
y = Mod[j + n/2, n] - n/2;
```

Minus one and modify parameters, I got this

[image: 15 frames from last 30 frames]

```
n = 64; dt = 0.3; mu = 0.0001; nt = 300;

vortex = Compile[{{v, _Real, 3}}, 
    With[{n = Length@v}, 
        Table[((v[[i + 1, j, 2]] - v[[i - 1, j, 2]]) - 
            (v[[i, j + 1, 1]] - v[[i, j - 1, 1]]))/2
        , {j, 2, n - 1}, {i, 2, n - 1}]]];
arrayplot = ArrayPlot[#, DataReversed -> True, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"] &;

vlst = Table[
    Do[
        Which[
            i <= 1 + n/16,
                v[[i, j]] = {0.1, 0.},
            (i - n/4)^2 + (j - n/2)^2 <= (n/16)^2,
                v[[i, j]] = {0., 0.}
        ]
    , {i, n}, {j, n}];
    {ui, vi} = Module[{umat = #},
        umat[[-1]] = umat[[1]]; 
        umat[[All, -1]] = umat[[All, 1]];
        ListInterpolation[umat, InterpolationOrder -> 1, PeriodicInterpolation -> True]
    ] & /@ separate@v;  
    v = Table[
        {i2, j2} = {i, j} - n dt v[[i, j]];
        {ui[i2, j2], vi[i2, j2]}
    , {i, n}, {j, n}];
    v = Fourier /@ separate@v // combine;
    v = Table[
        x = Mod[i + n/2-1, n] - n/2;
        y = Mod[j + n/2-1, n] - n/2;
        k = x^2 + y^2;
        Exp[-k dt mu] If[k > 0,
            (v[[i, j]] . {-y, x}/k) {-y, x},
            v[[i, j]]
        ]
    , {i, n}, {j, n}];
    v = InverseFourier /@ separate@v // combine //Re
, {t, nt}]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

Is that all?

Comment: Yes, this is the correct answer. Will award the bounty tomorrow morning. (You can set `nt` to `350` so we're within 5 keystrokes :) . )

Comment: It is a nice solution (+1).

Answer (score 6):

As well known the stably fluids algorithm is some kind of predictor corrector algorithm - see my answer [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/261185/3d-stable-fluids-algorithm-to-simulate-transition-from-laminar-to-turbulent-flow). This algorithm includes 3 steps - advection, diffusion and projection. In Fourie space the diffusion and projection can be combine in one step as follows

$(u-u_n)/dt+(u.\nabla) u=0, (u_{n+1}-u)/dt+\nabla p-\mu \nabla^2 u=0$

Apply $\nabla .$ to the last equation and use $\nabla .u_n=0$, then we have

$\nabla^2 p-\nabla. u/dt-\mu \nabla^2( \nabla .u)=0$

Using FFT we can transform last 2 linear equations to the system of algebraic equations and express $u_{n+1}$ Fourie image as

$\vec{u}_{n+1}=\vec{u}-(\vec{k}.\vec{u})\vec{k}/k^2+\mu dt k^2((\vec{k}.\vec{u})\vec{k}/k^2-\vec{u})$

where $\vec{k}=(k_x,k_y),k^2=k_x^2+k_y^2$.

Using Mathematica FFT, we should know how $k_x, k_y$ look like. These vectors are given by FFT matrix in a form

```
mat = Table[E^(2 \[Pi] I (r - 1) (s - 1)/n), {r, 1, n}, {s, 1, n}];r = (Log[Flatten[mat]]/I) // DeleteDuplicates;
```

Consequently, $k_x=r, k_y=r$ since FFT for matrix `A` in 2D is `mat.A.mat` (the normalization depends on `FourierParameters` option).  The final code is given by

```
n = 64; dt = 0.3; mu = 0.0001; nt = 300; mat = 
 Table[E^(
  2 \[Pi] I (r - 1) (s - 1)/n), {r, 1, n}, {s, 1, 
   n}]; r = (Log[Flatten[mat]]/I) // DeleteDuplicates;
v = Table[{0., 0.}, {n}, {n}];
separate = Transpose[#, {2, 3, 1}] &;
combine = Transpose[#, {3, 1, 2}] &;

g = Graphics[{Blue, Disk[{n/4, n/2}, n/16]}];


Do[Do[If[i < 1 + n/16, v[[i, j]] = {0.1, 0.}];
    If[(i - n/4)^2 + (j - n/2)^2 < (n/16)^2, 
     v[[i, j]] = {0., 0.}], {i, n}, {j, n}];
   {ui, vi} = Module[{umat = #}, umat[[-1]] = umat[[1]];
       umat[[All, -1]] = umat[[All, 1]];
       ListInterpolation[umat, InterpolationOrder -> 1, 
        PeriodicInterpolation -> True]] & /@ separate@v;
   v = Table[{i2, j2} = {i, j} - n dt v[[i, j]];
     {ui[i2, j2], vi[i2, j2]}, {i, n}, {j, n}];
   v = Fourier /@ separate@v // combine;
   v = Table[x = r[[i]];
     y = r[[j]];
     k = x^2 + y^2;
     If[k > 0, (v[[i, j]] - (v[[i, j]] . {x, y}) {x, y}/k) + 
       mu dt ((v[[i, j]] . {x, y}) {x, y} - k v[[i, j]]), 
      v[[i, j]]], {i, n}, {j, n}];
   v = (InverseFourier /@ separate@v // combine // Re); 
   vs[t] = v;, {t, nt}]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

It takes about one minute on my laptop. Visualization

```
lst = Table[
   Show[ListDensityPlot[
     Table[((vs[t][[i + 1, j, 2]] - 
           vs[t][[i - 1, j, 2]]) - (vs[t][[i, j + 1, 1]] - 
           vs[t][[i, j - 1, 1]]))/2, {j, 2, n - 1}, {i, 2, n - 1}], 
     Frame -> False, ColorFunction -> Hue, PlotRange -> All, 
     ImageSize -> Tiny], g], {t, 2, nt, 2}];
ListAnimate[lst]
```

[image: Figure 1]

Comment: I am not quite sure about your implementation. However, if you want to implement an simple spectral code using FFT with non-periodic boundary conditions the easiest way would be to consider a Chebyshev expansion in x-direction and a Fourier expansion in y-direction. Or both directions using Chebyshev.

Comment: "For one mode `i` and list length `n` it equals `2 Pi (i-1)/n`" Well, this is confusing. Isn't it something like: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/33625/1871 ? I mean, there's a shift in FFT, why it's not considered here?

Comment: @xzczd There are FFT and `FourieTransform`. Don't mixed up! Please, look attentively at FFT definition.

Comment: @ConvexHull You are right. We can't use FFT to solve this problem since domain has a hole.

Comment: Hmm… which part have I mixed up? For FFT, when $N$ is even, the frequency is from $0$ to $(\frac{N}{2}−1)Δf$, then $−\frac{N}{2}Δf$ to $−Δf$, right? In the original C code we can also find the shift using mod (`%` in C).

Comment: @xzczd Please, see definition FFT matrix.  The discrete Fourier transform $v_ s$ of a list $u_ r$ of length n is by default defined to be
$\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\sum _{r=1}^n u_re^{\frac{2 \pi  i (r-1) (s-1)}{n}}$.

Comment: Yeah, and for the last half, it rotates back e.g. `E^(6/5 I π (r - 1)) == E^(-4/5 I π (r - 1)) // Simplify[#, r ∈ Integers] &` returns `True`.

Comment: @xzczd Yes, it is, function `Exp` has this property, but expression for $u(k_x, k_y)$ above has not. It is why in your picture flow looks like rotated on $\pi/4$.

Comment: This is a bit embrassing… see my update for the question.

Comment: rnotlnglgq has found the correct answer so I can continue explaining: 1. The `Fourier` in this algorithm essentially plays the role of discrete, approximate Fourier transform, so we need to shift the frequency of `Fourier` to make it match with continuous Fourier transform. Please read the linked post above for more info. 2. Your way to calculate `k` won't reproduce Figure 6 in the paper. 3. Try using `grad = Grad[Exp[-x^2 - 2 y^2], {x, y}];curl = Curl[{0, 0, Exp[-2 x^2 - y^2]}, {x, y, z}] // Most; total=grad+curl` for testing, a correct Helmholtz decomposition should filter away the `grad`.

Comment: @xzczd I have tested my filter and filter proposed by rnotlnglgq, they are working absolutely same.

Comment: Try this: `Clear[x,y,z];n = 160; dn = 4/(n - 1.);datcurl = Table[curl, {x, -2, 2, dn}, {y, -2, 2, dn}];dat = Table[total, {x, -2, 2, dn}, {y, -2, 2, dn}];datf = Fourier /@ separate@dat // combine;v = With[{v = datf},Table[x = Mod[i - 1, n, -n/2];y = Mod[j - 1, n, -n/2];k = x^2 + y^2; If[k > 0, (v[[i, j]] . {-y, x}/k) {-y, x}, v[[i, j]]], {i, n}, {j, n}]];vAlex = With[{v = datf},Table[x=i-1;y=j-1;k=x^2+y^2+10^-16; k1=(2 Pi/n)^2 k;(v[[i, j]] - (v[[i, j]].{x, y}) {x, y}/k), {i, n},{j, n}]];Prepend[ListVectorPlot[Re[combine[InverseFourier/@separate[#]]]]&/@{v, vAlex}, datcurl // ListVectorPlot]`

Comment: @xzczd Thank you for this example. I see that `Max[Abs[(v - datcurl) // Re]]` is about 1.21243, and `Max[Abs[(vAlex - datcurl) // Re]]` is about 1.2143. While `Max[Abs[(vAlex - v) // Re]]` is about 0.227786. On the other hand, if we take `grad = {x, y}; curl = {-y, x};` then we have `Max[Abs[(vAlex - v) // Re]]` is about 2.50398*10^-15. ;)

Comment: You forgot to make the inverse transform. (Oops, I shouldn't have used `v` to represent transformed velocity… ) With `{x, -4, 4, dn}, {y, -4, 4, dn}`, `Max[Abs[(combine[InverseFourier /@ separate@v] - datcurl) // Re]]` gives `(* 4.89329*10^-9 *)`, but `Max[Abs[(combine[InverseFourier /@ separate@vAlex] - datcurl) // Re]]` gives `(* 0.516359 *)`.

Comment: @xzczd Yes, you are right. If we use same normalization at `k=0`, then `Max[Abs[(vAlex - v) ]]` is about 10^-15 for your test as well. I see, that my normalization is not good for some fields.

Comment: Interesting idea to make use of complex number to shift the frequency. It can be shorten to `r = Log@Table[E^(2 Pi I  (s - 1)/n), {s, n}]/I`. (For even `n`, the output of this method is slightly different from that given by `Mod`, the `n/2+1` element is shift to `Pi` instead of `-Pi`, but it's also valid, of course. ) As to the viscosity, you use the filter `(1 - k mu dt (Pi/(n/2))^2)` instead of `Exp[-k dt mu]` (here I use the convention in my code for `k`), if I understand it right, it's deduced from Fourier transform of $\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}=\mu  \frac{\partial ^2u}{\partial x^2}$?

Comment: @xzczd Actually diffusion step and projection step can be combined in one step as follows $(u-u_n)/dt+(u.\nabla) u=0, (u_{n+1}-u)/dt+\nabla p-\mu \nabla^2 u=0$. Apply $\nabla .$ to the last equation and use $\nabla. u_{n+1}=0$, then we have $\nabla^2 p-\nabla. u/dt-\mu \nabla^2( \nabla .u)=0$. So, we have two linear equations to be solved with FFT.

Comment: The filter `(1 - k mu dt (Pi/(n/2))^2)` is quite mild. Inspired by this, I notice viscosity is actually unnecessary to produce vortex street :D . See my update.

Comment: @xzczd Yes, we can compute vortex street at $\mu \rightarrow 0$ with this code. Thanks for this example. Now we have a good solver for some problems like  Kelvin-Helmholtz instability.

Comment: As to the new-added deduction, is $p$ simply ignored in last step because the algorithm doesn't involve pressure, or there's a deeper reason?

Comment: Use `p = pk Exp[I k1 x + I k2 y]; u = {uk, vk} Exp[I k1 x + I k2 y]; u1 = {u1k, v1k} Exp[I k1 x + I k2 y];` and solve equations `eq1 = Laplacian[p, {x, y}] - Div[u, {x, y}]/dt - 
  mu Laplacian[Div[u, {x, y}], {x, y}]==0; eq2 = (u1 - u)/dt + Grad[p, {x, y}] - mu Laplacian[u, {x, y}]` to express `pk, u1k, v1k`. Answer for velocity `{{u1k -> (
   k2^2 uk - dt k1^2 k2^2 mu uk - dt k2^4 mu uk - k1 k2 vk + 
    dt k1^3 k2 mu vk + dt k1 k2^3 mu vk)/(k1^2 + k2^2), 
  v1k -> (-k1 k2 uk + dt k1^3 k2 mu uk + dt k1 k2^3 mu uk + k1^2 vk - 
    dt k1^4 mu vk - dt k1^2 k2^2 mu vk)/(k1^2 + k2^2)}}`

Comment: Therefore, equation for Fourie velocity image does not depends on pressure while pressure is given by `pk -> (I (-k1 uk + dt k1^3 mu uk + dt k1 k2^2 mu uk - k2 vk + 
     dt k1^2 k2 mu vk + dt k2^3 mu vk))/(dt (k1^2 + k2^2))`

Comment: Yeah, it's possible to eliminate $p$, but $\vec{u}_{n+1}=\vec{u}-(\vec{k}.\vec{u})\vec{k}/k^2+\mu dt k^2((\vec{k}.\vec{u})\vec{k}/k^2-\vec{u})$ is deduced from $((u_{n+1}-u)/dt+\nabla p-\mu \nabla^2 u)-(\nabla^2 p-\nabla. u/dt-\mu \nabla^2( \nabla .u))$, right? In this case, $\nabla p$ and $\nabla^2 p$ won't cancel.

Comment: No, $p$ computed from `eq1= Laplacian[p, {x, y}] - Div[u, {x, y}]/dt -    mu Laplacian[Div[u, {x, y}], {x, y}]==0`, while $\vec{u}_{n+1}$ computed from $(u_{n+1}-u)/dt+\nabla p-\mu \nabla^2 u=0$.

Comment: Oops… you're right. Sorry, I've made some silly mistakes. (Seems I'm too tired…)

Answer (score 0):

You must tell ListDensityPlot that it should print the image, otherwise it is absorbed in the Do loop.

From the following code I get 25 images. Due to space, I only show the first and last. I am not sure if it is what you want:

```
n = 64; dt = 0.3; mu = 0.001; v = Table[{0, 0}, {n}, {n}];

    Do[
      
      Do[If[i < 5, v[[i, j]] = {0.1, 0}];
       If[(i - n/4)^2 + (j - n/2)^2 < 4^2, v[[i, j]] = {0, 0}], {i, 1, 
        n}, {j, 1, n}];
      
      ui = ListInterpolation[v[[All, All, 1]]];
      vi = ListInterpolation[v[[All, All, 2]]];
      
      {ui, vi} = 
       Module[{ui = #}, ui[[-1]] = ui[[1]]; ui[[All, -1]] = ui[[All, 1]];
          ListInterpolation[ui, InterpolationOrder -> 1, 
           PeriodicInterpolation -> True]] & /@ Transpose[v, {2, 3, 1}];
      
      v = Table[{i2, j2} = {i, j} - n dt v[[i, j]];
        {ui[i2, j2], vi[i2, j2]}, {i, 1, n}, {j, 1, n}];
      
      v = Transpose[Map[Fourier[v[[All, All, #]]] &, {1, 2}], {3, 1, 2}];
      v = Table[x = Mod[i + n/2, n] - n/2;
        y = Mod[j + n/2, n] - n/2;
        k = x^2 + y^2;
        Exp[-k dt mu] If[k > 0, (v[[i, j]] . {-y, x}/k) {-y, x}, 
          v[[i, j]]], {i, 1, n}, {j, 1, n}];
      v = Transpose[
        Map[Re[InverseFourier[v[[All, All, #]]]] &, {1, 2}], {3, 1, 2}];
      ListDensityPlot[
        Table[((v[[i + 1, j, 2]] - v[[i - 1, j, 2]]) - (v[[i, j + 1, 1]] -
               v[[i, j - 1, 1]]))/2, {j, 2, n - 1}, {i, 2, n - 1}], 
        Mesh -> False, Frame -> False, ColorFunction -> (Hue[2 #/3] &)] //
        Print, {t, 1, 25}];
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: As already mentioned in 1st possible issue of question, this isn't a big problem, the real problem is, the obtained picture is vastly different from the GIF.