# FEM: modelling 2D flow under periodic forcing

Tags: finite-element-method, physics, boundary-conditions

Despite many examples of periodic boundary conditions being presented, it remains difficult to obtain a periodic solution. Let us consider a simple example of a flow in a two-dimensional channel under the action of a vertical force `Cos[\[Pi] x + \[Pi]/4]`, periodic boundary conditions in `x` direction and free-slip at bottom and top

```
l = 2; h = 1;
\[CapitalOmega] = Rectangle[{0, 0}, {l, h}];
op = {Derivative[1, 0, 0][u][t, x, 
      y] + \[Nu] Inactive[
        Div][-Inactive[Grad][u[t, x, y], {x, y}], {x, y}] + {u[t, x, 
        y], v[t, x, y]} . Inactive[Grad][u[t, x, y], {x, y}] + 
     Derivative[0, 1, 0][p][t, x, y],
    Derivative[1, 0, 0][v][t, x, 
      y] + \[Nu] Inactive[
        Div][-Inactive[Grad][v[t, x, y], {x, y}], {x, y}] + {u[t, x, 
        y], v[t, x, y]} . Inactive[Grad][v[t, x, y], {x, y}] + 
     Derivative[0, 0, 1][p][t, x, y] - 
     Cos[\[Pi] x + \[Pi]/4] (1 - Exp[-t 10^-1]), 
    Derivative[0, 1, 0][u][t, x, y] + 
     Derivative[0, 0, 1][v][t, x, y]} /. \[Nu] -> 10^-1;
ic = {u[0, x, y] == 0, v[0, x, y] == 0, p[0, x, y] == 0};
bcD = {DirichletCondition[
    v[t, x, y] == 0, (y == 0 || y == h) && 0 <= x <= l], 
   DirichletCondition[p[t, x, y] == 0, x == l && y == 0]};
bcN = {NeumannValue[0, (y == 0 || y == h) && 0 <= x <= l], 0, 0};
bcP = {PeriodicBoundaryCondition[u[t, x, y], x == 0 && 0 < y < h, 
    TranslationTransform[{l, 0}]], 
   PeriodicBoundaryCondition[v[t, x, y], x == 0 && 0 < y < h, 
    TranslationTransform[{l, 0}]], 
   PeriodicBoundaryCondition[p[t, x, y], x == 0 && 0 < y <= h, 
    TranslationTransform[{l, 0}]]};
tmax = 1; Monitor[
 AbsoluteTiming[{xVel, yVel, pressure} = 
    NDSolveValue[
     Flatten@{op == bcN, bcD, bcP, ic}, {u, v, 
      p}, {x, y} \[Element] \[CapitalOmega], {t, 0, tmax}, 
     Method -> {"PDEDiscretization" -> {"MethodOfLines", 
         "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement", 
           "InterpolationOrder" -> {u -> 2, v -> 2, p -> 1}}}}, 
     EvaluationMonitor :> (currentTime = 
        Row[{"t=", CForm[t]}])];], currentTime];
```

The result does not look periodic

```
Row[{StreamDensityPlot[{xVel[tmax, x, y], 
    yVel[tmax, x, y]}, {x, y} \[Element] xVel["ElementMesh"], 
   AspectRatio -> Automatic, PlotRange -> All, StreamPoints -> Fine, 
   PlotLegends -> Placed[Automatic, Top], ImageSize -> 300], 
  ContourPlot[
   pressure[tmax, x, y], {x, y} \[Element] pressure["ElementMesh"], 
   AspectRatio -> Automatic, PlotRange -> All, 
   ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap", 
   PlotLegends -> Placed[Automatic, Top], ImageSize -> 300, 
   Contours -> 10, PlotRange -> All]}]
```

[image]

I've tried to put `PeriodicBoundaryCondition` on both sides

```
bcP = {PeriodicBoundaryCondition[u[t, x, y], x == l && 0 < y < h, 
    TranslationTransform[{-l, 0}]], 
   PeriodicBoundaryCondition[v[t, x, y], x == l && 0 < y < h, 
    TranslationTransform[{-l, 0}]], 
   PeriodicBoundaryCondition[p[t, x, y], x == l && 0 < y <= h, 
    TranslationTransform[{-l, 0}]], 
   PeriodicBoundaryCondition[u[t, x, y], x == 0 && 0 < y < h, 
    TranslationTransform[{l, 0}]],
   PeriodicBoundaryCondition[v[t, x, y], x == 0 && 0 < y < h, 
    TranslationTransform[{l, 0}]], 
   PeriodicBoundaryCondition[p[t, x, y], x == 0 && 0 < y <= h, 
    TranslationTransform[{l, 0}]]};
```

and result is getting better
[image]

but still it is not satisfying. Also the trick with ghost layer did not wowrk. I can get almost periodic flow only if I will heavily extended area taking `l=10`. Then right flow looks like
[image]

So, can anyone who is familiar with FEM help me set up the periodic boundary correctly?

Comment: How you know what period is for this flow? Periodic in space force produces some flow that may be not periodic or periodic with some unknown period.  On the other hand periodic in time force generates periodic flow like in my post on https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/246091/stable-fluids-code-for-electromagnetic-mixture-application

Comment: You're right. I forgot to mention that I consider the Reynolds number to be very low, so the flow remains quasi-linear and periodic.

Comment: The flow has a period of force or shorter but multiples of it..

Comment: Actually for `l=10` the Reynolds number is about 2, and it is why on the plots `Plot[xVel[tmax, x, .1], {x, 0, l}, PlotRange -> All]` , `Plot[pressure[tmax, x, .5], {x, 0, l}, PlotRange -> All]` we can recognize anharmonic oscillations. What kind of solution do you try to reproduce with your `bcD`?

Comment: I look for ``bcP`` definition which provide periodic solution so that  fields (u,v,f) satisfy ``f(x+l,y)=f(x,y)`` and ``f'(x+l,y)=f'(x,y)``. If you want I can you analytical solution.